# Is there a Vedic yajna that can grant wishes?

Tags: vedas, yajna, vedic-rituals

Karma kanda has many yajnas which can give heaven and such other fruitive activities, is there mention of yajna which can fulfill a wish? Are there any
rituals, yajnas, vratas, mantras or praying to a specific deity that can fulfill wishes.

Comment: There are many yajnas and mantras to fulfill wishes. What is the exact wish you are thinking of?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I want to prove that all the Hindu scriptures are 5000 year old. And prove that Mahabharata took place.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma and bring back the lost scriptures too.

Comment: a well-preserved version of atharva veda paippalada was discovered among a collection of palm leaf manuscripts in Odisha in 1957.  there might be a few more undiscovered manuscripts out there.  Sorry rig veda cannot be pushed beyond 1500 b.c.  Later scriptures get dated firmly using non-Hindu sources and historical linguistics as much younger than rig veda.

Comment: @SK I don't need your suggestions.

Comment: max mueller was not a linguist.  my comments are for the record, not individuals.

Comment: @SK all Vedas are atlest 5000 year old.

Comment: Yes, there is. Scriptures are full of that: you can repeat God's name (You can take initiation in a mantra with a proper guru) and repeat it until God himself appear before you. Then you can ask whatever wish you want. BTW, also in scritures, devas ask good qualities (vivek, vairagya, moksha, mumuksha) and asuras ask for selfish qualities (to live forever, to become invinsible, etc). In case of confution we can ask God to choose for us what is better, and that is total pranidhana, total surrender. But the short answer is God's name repetition can make God appear before you and then you can ask

Comment: We don't have many written works from 5000 BCE. The system of writing down only began some 4,500 years ago. @SK is right. Also, there is a language called Avestan, used to write the holy books of the Parsees, which are dated to about 1320 BC.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I am facing severe racial discrimination. And I am from poor family. So I cannot afford legal alternative. Despite working hard for many years I am facing many problems in life. Please tell me any tapa, any japa, any anushthan, any purasharan, any temple or any vrat so that I can get justice, freedom, equal treatment in society and get peaceful life. I have worked very hard and tried everything I can do. But still I'm struggling. I am ready to do hardest vrat, tapa etc. Please guide me. I can't afford to go to court against govt because I am not that rich and it's time consuming.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma please tell me any concrete solution. You'll surely be blessed.

Answer (score 3):

There are many instances in the Puranas where people have worshiped a variety of gods to fulfill their wishes. Most of the times the ones invoked are from the Trinity - Lord Brahma, Shiva and Vishnu but there are also instances of the Goddess or some other deity being invoked for the fulfillment of a specific wish.

However, since your question is primarily about Vedic Yagnas, I am sharing the following excerpt from the **[Shatapatha Brahmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe44/sbe44008.htm)** that mentions a wish-fulfilling sacrifice performed by no less that Brahma & his sons:

> 16. They went on singing praises and toiling. Then Parameshthin, son of Pragâpati, saw that sacrifice, **the New and Full-moon offerings,** and performed these offerings. Having performed them, he desired, 'Would I were everything here!' He became the waters, for the waters are everything here, inasmuch as they abide in the furthest place; for he who digs here on earth finds indeed water; and, in truth, it is from that furthest place, to wit, from yonder sky that he 1 rains, whence the name Parameshthin (abiding in the furthest, highest place).
> 17. **Parameshthin spake unto his father Pragâpati, 'I have discovered a sacrifice which fulfils wishes:** let me perform this for thee!'--'So be it!' he said. He accordingly performed it for him. Having sacrificed, he (Pragâpati) desired, **'Would I were everything here!' He became the breath (vital air), for breath is everything here:** Pragâpati is that breath which blows here (the wind); and whatsoever knows that it is thus he blows is his (Pragâpati's) eyesight; and whatsoever is endowed with breath is Pragâpati. And, verily, whosoever thus knows that eyesight of Pragâpati becomes, as it were, manifest.
> 18. Pragâpati spake unto his son Indra, 'Let me perform for thee **this wish-fulfilling sacrifice which Parameshthin has just performed for me.**'--'So be it!' he said. He accordingly performed it for him. Having sacrificed, he **(Indra) desired, 'Would that I were everything here!' He became speech (vâk), for speech is everything here;** whence they say, 'Indra is Vâk.'
> 19. Indra spake unto his brothers Agni and Soma, 'Let me perform for you this **wish-fulfilling sacrifice** which our father Pragâpati has just performed for me.'--'So be it!' they said. He accordingly performed it for them. Having sacrificed, **those two desired, 'Would that we were everything here!' One of them became the eater of food, and the other became food: Agni became the eater of food, and Soma food; and the eater of food, and food, indeed, are everything here.**
> 20. These five deities, then, performed that wish-fulfilling sacrifice; and **for whatever wish they sacrificed, that wish of theirs was fulfilled;
>     and, verily, for whatever wish one performs that sacrifice, that wish
>     of his is fulfilled.**

The New and Full Moon Sacrifice is also called **DARSAPÛRNAMÂSA-ISHTÎ** in the **[first Kands of the Shatapath Brahmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1203.htm)** and this seems to be the most clear mention of a wish-fulfilling Vedic sacrifice that even helped Lord Brahma and his sons fulfill their desires.

Comment: What is the name of that sacrifice?

Comment: @TatTvamAsi found the name as - DARSAPÛRNAMÂSA-ISHTÎ and have added it in the answer with the link to the ritual.

Comment: @Dr. Vineet Aggarwal I'm facing severe racial discrimination. And I am from poor family. So I cannot afford legal alternative. Despite working hard for many years I am facing many problems in life. Please tell me any tapa, any japa, any anushthan, any purasharan, any temple or any vrat so that I can get justice, freedom, equal treatment in society and get peaceful life. I've worked very hard and tried everything I can do. But still struggling. I'm ready to do hardest vrat, tapa etc. Please guide me. I can't afford to go to court against govt because I am not that rich and it's time consuming.

Comment: @ramanujan sorry to hear about your situation and my heartfelt sympathies with you. Unfortunately I am not a guru qualified enough to guide someone and my answer is based on what I have read from the scriptures. You may try the above mentioned fast after consulting with a qualified Guru and I hope everything goes well for you!

Comment: @Dr. Vineet Aggarwal thanks